# Android method doesnot work at html

Tags: android, html, android-layout

> I created new **Android** App as it display static information , i had created html5 and i call **html5** files to my **webview** one of my html files function is play mp3 when click on button I did my interface between html and **android** but the **mp3** didn't play .

```
public class WebAppInterface extends Activity  {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}


public void audioPlayer() {
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("Azan.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    //Call HTML Files
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.x);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    //initiate interface 

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");


}
```

```
 <input type="button" value="play mp3" onClick="playmp3()" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function playmp3()
 {
    Android.audioPlayer();
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `Java` method as `window.Android.audioPlayer();`.
Just add `window` at the begining